# Android can't find my sound files (and dev)

Tags: android, audio, loading

I attempted to make a soundboard and my app crashed when loading sounds.

```
mSoundManager.addSound(0, 0, R.raw.b_behold);
ERROR: Source not found.
```

It gives me an option to `Edit Source Lookup path`, But I can't seem to get that to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

rename the sound file, close eclipse, open it, refresh tour project and retyping the R.raw.[soundFileName]

It is something stupid with eclipse and happened to me many times before :(
I hope this will solve it

Godd Luck !

Comment: I tried that... Still didn't work :(
Maybe, do u know how you are supposed to import audio files into your project... I simply dragged my audio files into the res-raw from inside the IDE (eclipse)

Comment: I simply copy-and-paste them in the res/raw folder ! Ok then, what is mSoundManager? of what type?

Comment: its another java class... I  actually forget what they are called... Its been ages since I did java

It calls a fuction which does this:
mSoundPoolMap[tabNum].put(Index, mSoundPool[tabNum].load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
Where mSoundPoolMap is a map<int, int>.. btw, Before (I was using a soundboard example) the sounds worked fine... I have eddited it slightly, but I doubt it is the problem... It's saying it cant find the audio files....

Comment: Try to start the index file with 1. i.e `mSoundManager.addSound(1, 0, R.raw.b_behold);`. Don't ask me why :)

Comment: thats what it was b4... ill try

Comment: is the sound file a .ogg one ?